# How to combine Haskell code with Objective-C for iOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, haskell, functional-programming, interop

I want to start iOS development and I' m very interested in the ways of using Haskell language as opposed to the Objective-C/C++ in the iOS environment. Let's suppose that we have some Haskell code which uses different Haskell libraries and we want to reuse it in iOS project (not for production).

So the question: are there some ready for use solutions for this purpose (libraries, bridges, frameworks, etc.)?

Comment: You probably already came across this but in case you didn't: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IPhone

Comment: Key point from there: `3 GHC as a cross compiler: ... Haskell code should be compiled into static library. Because custom dynamically linked libraries are not allowed in regular iOS (not jail-breaken).`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4722685/493729

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/ghc-ios and https://github.com/jfischoff/ghc-ios-simple-setup

Comment: If this is a question about exporting an application and its patterns from one language to another, it might be worth asking over at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the past I used [HOC](http://code.google.com/p/hoc/) to generate Haskell bindings to Objective C APIs.